# CodeIgniter: Make a multilevel combobox using ajax.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, combobox

I've a problem when showing multilevel combo-box using ajax.
When I change my value data, the second combo-box is not shown.

Here's my code.. (controller)

```
$data['kategori_2'] = $this->barang_model->get_category();
```

on my model

```
function get_category(){
    $main_category_id = $this->input->post('main_category_id');
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('main_category_id',$main_category_id);
    $this->db->order_by('id','ASC');
    $array_keys_values = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($array_keys_values->result() as $row)
    {
        $result[0]= '-Pilih Kategori Anak-';
        $result[$row->id]= $row->category_name;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

on my views (code only)

```
<?php
    echo form_dropdown("id",$kategori_2,'');
?>
```

The Ajax's code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id").change(function(){
            var id = {id:$("#id").val()};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "<?php echo site_url('admin/barang/add')?>",
                    data: id,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#category').html(msg);
                    }
                });
    });
   </script>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: have you check console error

Comment: Thank you sir.. sorry for my bad english.. :)

Comment: using firebug or any other debug tool

Comment: sorry I can't do that sir, I'm a newbie... can you give me the solution?

Comment: where is #category in view

Comment: I don't make it sir, what should I do? Or any alternative for my code?

Comment: you need to make an element which have id="catagory" then  $('#category').html(msg); will work and will show your output in this element

Comment: I did it but return a zero values...

Comment: check success: function(msg){ alert(msg);
                        $('#category').html(msg);
                    } what you get output